# unknown USB symbols in antique module for linux kernel 2.6.27

Tags: module, linux-kernel, virtualbox, fedora

I am trying to revive an old linux USB module called Wind River v6 (wndrvr6), originally written for the 2.6.18 or earlier kernels, probably RedHat 5.  The oldest kernel I have managed to get running adequately under Virtualbox is 2.6.27 in Fedora 9, and everything works okay except for this one module. I made about 10 changes to the source code to get it to compile with 2.6.27, but when I try to load it, I get

windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_alloc_urb
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_free_urb
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_ifnum_to_if
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_register_driver
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_clear_halt
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_submit_urb
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_set_interface
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_deregister
windrvr6: Unknown symbol usb_kill_urb

I have run "depmod -a", and "depmod -e" gives no output, so all symbols should be accounted for.  The symbols above appear in many modules (using the strings command).  /proc/kallsyms has the line

ffffffff811efc29 T usb_kill_urb

so these symbols are provided.  Why are these symbols not found?

Comment: usb_kill_urb is exported using EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL().  What is the licensing of windrvr6 driver?  That may be the cause of the link failure.  See the USB core code here:  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/core/urb.c?v=3.3#L615

Comment: The code says to see "\windriver\docs\license.txt", but Xilinx did not include the docs directory with the source. Last time I wrote a device driver, licensing was not checked.  This driver only calls EXPORT_SYMBOL() and EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS(). There is some code regarding licensing in the source, but it is a maze of twisty little macros, all alike.

Comment: I don't think EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS() works anymore with most kernels above 2.6.x.  I ran into a similar problem within the last 6 months with modversioning.  It wouldn't matter anyway as the module licensing policy does not consider versioning but license, which would be advertised using the MODULE_LICENSE() macro.  The design intention is to prevent closed source drivers from using GPL licensed code.  You also have the option of building the driver as part of the kernel.  See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/export.h#L89 for how this is implemented in the kernel.

Comment: This driver is actually called WinDriver (from Jungo), and is spelled `windrvr6`.  This may help in your Google searches.  Many devices which claim to need windrvr6 (Xilinx FPGA programmers for example) are actually now compatible with libusb, and no longer need windrvr6 at all.

Comment: EXPORT_SYMBOL_NOVERS() is called for outgoing symbols, not incoming symbols.  It may be an issue, but it isn't related to the issue I am having now.  Also, compatibility with a modern libusb does me no good, since I am trying to run a libusb from 2008.

Comment: I tried XP under VirtualBox instead.  The drivers load fine, but XP doesn't find the driver when the Spartan-3AN development board USB cable is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the most recent version of the driver from Jungo, which built just fine. When I swapped out the source code files but used the old configure & makefile scripts, then the problem returned.  The issue then, whatever it was, was due to a problem with the compilation or installation of the module. At any rate, I now have an installed driver.